# php submit javascript form

Tags: php, javascript, parsing, autofill

I'm parsing a website with `php` to retrieve data. Part of the data becomes visible after selecting values in a `javascript` combobox.

Is their a way for `php` to select a value in the combobox, submit it and handle result?

Comment: Php can't run on the client side. If your want to use php in the browser it's impossible.

Comment: yes it is possible ,,using web scrap you can bring all the result from the other site and you can even fetch the result of the site after submit and result will be as expected...

Comment: I know php is serve-side but on selection of the combo box the data changes. I'm interested in that new data. I'll see what firebug can tell me about the process of submitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `Developer Tools` from `Chrome` on the `network tab`. This allowed me to capture the `form data` that is been posted with the `javascript` combobox.

With `cURL` I performed the post in `php`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not. You will have to dissect the page you are scraping to see where the data that becomes visible comes from. Use Firebug to help you.